# how to select max value from a subquery in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How come this SQL query doesn't work?

```
select max(t.salary) as salary from
(SELECT department_id "department Id", SUM(salary) "salary"  FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY department_id) t;
```

It shows "salary is invalid identifier " error

Comment: I guess, the issue is in double quotes, you can use ` instead of "

Comment: Either use backticks instead of double quotes or enable ANSI_QUOTES.

Comment: "I'm using Oracle" so please choose that as a tag to your question - don't choose MySQL unless both databases are relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT SUM(salary) AS salary  
FROM EMPLOYEES 
GROUP BY department_id
ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: can't use group by and order by together

Comment: @esokumamon ??? why?

Comment: gives an error.

Comment: @esokumamon You do something wrongly. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5537d15f1be0dbbb049143e5859e332 Show complete query text which you're executing and complete error message text.

Comment: I'm using oracle

Comment: @esokumamon [facepalm] MySQL <> OracleDB !!! Edit question tags accordingly. In Oracle use `FETCH` instead of LIMIT. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a7ad77afc4919ef838b0c11ea9847f83

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(t.salary) as salary 
from(
    SELECT department_id AS `department Id`, SUM(salary) AS `salary`
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    GROUP BY department_id
) AS t
```